# Is there some way to delay (or stream) clipboard operations in AWT / Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt, clipboard

I have a table with a million rows.

If I select all rows and Copy, it takes approximately 5 minutes before responsiveness returns to the GUI and before I can paste it into another application. This is less than great, so I started looking for improvements.

If I make an alternative thread-safe TableModel, then I can background the operation of building the string and then push to the clipboard (on the EDT, if need be). Then the GUI is responsive, but it is still 5 minutes before I can paste into another application, which in some ways is a worse experience, because at least when it blocked the EDT, I was able to tell when the operation finished. I know I could add GUI feedback for it, but it seems wrong for an action like Copy.

If I look at the same thing happening between native applications, I notice that I can copy an enormous amount of data from one application with no delay. I can then immediately paste it into another application with no delay, but just with the caveat that it can take a long time for *all* the information to end up in there. For instance, if I paste huge text from TextEdit into Terminal, it seems to do this a bit at a time somehow.

Is there some way to do that in AWT as well?

I attempted to do it by only declaring the alternate flavours returning `Reader` and `InputStream`, but it turns out that even if you do this, it asks for the reader one, fetches the reader and then immediately reads the entire stream, storing it as a string. So this just moves the 5 minute delay to code inside the JRE, solving nothing. This is also fairly stupid, because there is this whole framework around what type of data transfer methods your `Transferable` supports, yet no matter which type you expose, the system seems to convert it down to the same type, which in the best case will take forever to build, or in the worst case will run you out of heap.

Maybe there is a type which doesn't though, so I thought I'd post this question to ask whether anyone knows.

Example of one `TransferHandler`, although the built-in one on `JTable` itself exhibits the same issue.

```
private class CombinedTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent component) {
        if (component instanceof JTable) {
            JTable table = (JTable) component;

            int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
            if (!table.getRowSelectionAllowed()) {
                int rowCount = table.getRowCount();

                rows = new int[rowCount];
                for (int counter = 0; counter < rowCount; counter++) {
                    rows[counter] = counter;
                }
            }

            // columns omitted because we know we use all
            return new BasicTransferable(getPlainData(rows), null);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY;
    }

    private String getPlainData(int[] rows) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        int staticColumnCount = staticTable.getColumnCount();
        int mainColumnCount = mainTable.getColumnCount();
        for (int row : rows) {
            for (int viewColumn = 0; viewColumn < staticColumnCount;
                 viewColumn++) {
                if (viewColumn > 0) {
                    result.append('\t');
                }

                Object value = staticTable.getValueAt(row, viewColumn);
                value = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
                result.append(value);
            }

            for (int viewColumn = 0; viewColumn < mainColumnCount;
                 viewColumn++) {
                if (staticColumnCount > 0 || viewColumn > 0) {
                    result.append('\t');
                }

                Object value = mainTable.getValueAt(row, viewColumn);
                value = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
                result.append(value);
            }

            result.append('\n');
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make a copy of the `TableModel` (in part or in whole either directly or just the data you need) and then run a `SwingWorker` to generate the "copy"? There could also be inefficiencies in the way you are generating the output so runnabe example might help highlight areas of oppurtunites

Comment: Data transfer is funny thing, for example, all you really need is the "data", when the "export" method is called, you'd then need to format it base on the required `DataFlavor`

Comment: There really isn't enough to the code we're running to demand an example. There might be inefficiencies, sure. For instance, we're using StringBuilder and might not be giving it the best maximum size. But even if we made it 10 times faster, a table 10 times bigger would still take 5 minutes, so I was looking for some kind of ultimate solution. I don't suppose DataFlavor allows me to jam in any declared type I want...

Comment: Well, it depends, what format do you want the data in?  If it's just plain text, then it's rather simple, if formatted or html or an image, then it becomes more complicated

Comment: It's just plain text. The problem is that the plain text takes 5 minutes to generate because I/O has to be performed in order to get the values.

Comment: Okay, so the issue is more to do with the I/O overhead than anything else. In that case, I'd be looking at strategies to further limit that

Comment: Never going to happen... plus, even if I sped that up 10 times, someone would just show me a table with 10 times more items which would still be slow.

Comment: *"Never going to happen..."* - Then frankly, you're screwed, unless you can find a way to reduce that overhead. Off the top of my head (without doing any other testing), there are `Reader` and `InputStream` readers, but I doubt they would help, as you'd still need to format the stream

Comment: Actually the formatting of the stream is easy enough. I can even do that in a streaming fashion one table row at a time (this is one of the quick fixes I already tried.) But even if I hand back a Reader, the JRE still reads the entire stream up-front anyway, so it doesn't really change things. :(